# Prevent the n+1 in an eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Currently, when I'm retrieving the 'messages', it is presenting the `n+1` issue:

```
select * from `messages` where `messages`.`alert_id` = '21'
```

This sometimes is replicated over 100+ times!

Controller function:

```
public function getIndex() {
    $alerts = Alert::with('location')
              ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
              ->get();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('agents.index', 
                                   array('alerts' => $alerts));
}
```

Alert Model:

```
public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Location');
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Message');
}
```

Message Model:

```
public function alert()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Alert');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

If I use the following line of code, I can see the MYSQL is correct, but it then can't find the `location` method:

```
$alerts = Alert::with('messages.location')
```

> select * from `messages` where `messages`.`alert_id` in ('21', '42')

I think it maybe a relationship issue, but I'm unsure of how to resolve it. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand but I'm thinking that you are trying to get an Alert with its messages and its location. I would do:

```
public function getIndex() {
    $alerts = Alert::with('location', 'messages')
              ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
              ->get();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('agents.index', 
                                   array('alerts' => $alerts));
}
```

to use eager loading on messages and location for your Alert.

Comment: `$company = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->companies()->with('users.alerts.location.messages')->first();` Is there a reason why this won't work @Antoine Augusti? It's unable to find the `messages` method?

Comment: @Svengali Without your User model it's hard to tell. What are you trying to get? My guess: `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->with('companies', 'alerts', 'alerts.location', 'alerts.messages'‌​)->first();` Read again this part of the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading especially for nested relationships.

Comment: User model: `public function companies()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Company');
}`

`public function alerts()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Alert');
}`